# How to add a custom padding between the TabLayout tabIndicator and the TabItem text?

Tags: android, layout, padding, tablelayout, tabitem

I want to move the tab text gravity on top to add more padding between the tabIndicator and the text by maintaining the same tabLayout height. Is there a way to achieve that? adding a padding on the tabItem doesn't work.On the below image, the arrow shows the place I want to increase the padding.

[image: TabLayout with tabIndicator]

Comment: `TabItem`s aren't actual `View`s that end up in the `TabLayout`, so most regular `View` attributes don't work for them. Try setting `app:tabPaddingBottom` on the `<TabLayout>` instead.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM., that works well for my case.